# Jquery - ul slidedown slideup

Tags: jquery, html, slidedown, slideup

i having problems with my menu dropdown and dont know why. Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
                            <li>
                                <font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Quartos e Suites</a></font>
                                <img src="imgs/DownArrow.gif" class="arrowup" style="width:13px;height:13px">
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Suite Presidencial</a></font></li>
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Suite Executiva</a></font></li>
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Suite Junior</a></font></li>
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Quarto Superior</a></font></li>
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Quarto Standart</a></font></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=2" class="links">Restaurante e Bar</a></font>
                                <img src="imgs/DownArrow.gif" class="arrowup" style="width:13px;height:13px">
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Suite Presidencial</a></font></li>
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Suite Executiva</a></font></li>
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Suite Junior</a></font></li>
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Quarto Superior</a></font></li>
                                    <li><font style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="?id=1" class="links">Quarto Standart</a></font></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
```

and the jquery:

```
$('.arrowup').click(function(){        
    var menu = $(this).next('ul');  
    var thisimage = $(this);
        //check if is any open and close
        allmenu = $('.submenu:visible');
        if(allmenu.size() != 0){
           allmenu.slideUp(function(){ 
                $(this).prev('img').attr('src', 'imgs/DownArrow.gif'); 
                //check is the one is closing is not the one clicked
                if($(this).not(menu)){
                   menu.slideDown(function(){ 
            thisimage.attr('src', 'imgs/UpArrow.gif');      
        });
                }       
       });
        }else{
        //open the one clicked
         alert(3);
         $(this).next('ul').slideDown(function(){ 
            thisimage.attr('src', 'imgs/UpArrow.gif');      
        });  
        } 
});
```

The main problem here is when the one that is open is clicked to close, it close and open.
the error is here: if($(this).not(menu)). but dont know why.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Possibly replace this code:

```
            if($(this).not(menu)){
               menu.slideDown(function(){ 
        thisimage.attr('src', 'imgs/UpArrow.gif');      
    });
            }
```

with this:

```
               menu.not(this).slideDown(function(){ 
        thisimage.attr('src', 'imgs/UpArrow.gif');      
    });
```

Explanation: "[not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)" takes a set of elements, filters it, and returns a new set of elements that don't match a selector, reference, or function. It is meaningless and useless to test that set of elements in an if statement. A jQuery element collection is basically a fancy array, and all arrays in Javascript are considered true when converted to a boolean, even if they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you test if has any submenu opened, you should just close them, so the if statement `if ( $(this).not(menu) )` and inner code should be removed.

PS: from jQuery site, `.not()` method return a jQuery object, then that if statement is wrong due to it always be true...

What you should do is: test if the `menu` is opened and store it into a variable, then close all submenus opened, then if `opened` is false, open the `menu`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.arrowup').click(function(){        
    var menu = $(this).next('ul');  
    var thisimage = $(this);
        //check if is any open and close
        allmenu = $('.submenu:visible');
        if(menu.is(':visible')){

        }else{
            if(allmenu.size() != 0){             
                allmenu.slideUp(function(){ 
                    $(this).prev('img').attr('src', 'imgs/DownArrow.gif');
                     menu.slideDown();      
                });

            }else{
                //open the one clicked
                 $(this).next('ul').slideDown(function(){ 
                    thisimage.attr('src', 'imgs/UpArrow.gif');      
                });  
            } 
        }       
});
```